# Transposing a part of the rdd row

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a requirement where I need to transpose only certain elements of each RDD row element. I have below input file.

```
sno|fname |lname |f1 |f2  |f3  |f4
1  |sunil |kumar |500|1000|2000|3000
2  |mahesh|kalani|600|700 |800 |1000
```

I need the oputput as below.

```
1|sunil |kumar |f1|500
1|sunil |kumar |f2|1000
1|sunil |kumar |f3|2000
1|sunil |kumar |f4|3000
2|mahesh|kalani|f1|600
2|mahesh|kalani|f2|700
2|mahesh|kalani|f3|800
2|mahesh|kalani|f4|1000
```

How can I write a mapper function on the RDD to get the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flatMap`:

```
rdd.flatMap {
  case (sno, fname, name, f1, f2, f3, f4) => 
    List("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4").zip(List(f1, f2, f3, f4)).map {
      case (k, v) => (sno, fname, name, k, v)
    }
}
```

This is assuming you already have removed the header row, and parsed each other row as a tuple.

**EDIT**

To parse each row as a tuple, you can do as follow:

```
rawRdd.map(row => row.split("|") match {
  case Array(sno, fname, name, f1, f2, f3, f4) => (sno, fname, name, f1, f2, f3, f4)
}
```

Note that you might as well merge the two steps into one, using only `flatMap`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried the above code on spark-shell and got below error.  scala> val rdd2 = rdd1.drop(1).flatMap { case (sno, fname, name, f1, f2, f3, f4) => List("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4").zip(List(f1, f2, f3, f4)).map { case (k, v) => (sno, fname, name, k, v) } }
<console>:29: error: value drop is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
         val rdd2 = rdd1.drop(1).flatMap { case (sno, fname, name, f1, f2, f3, f4) => List("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4").zip(List(f1, f2, f3, f4)).map { case (k, v) => (sno, fname, name, k, v) } }
                         ^

Comment: Sorry, I made some assumption on `RDD` without checking with a compiler before answering. The `drop(1)` part is just to remove headers, which you probably want to do anyway. There is an option to do so, depending on how you load your data into your `RDD`.

Comment: i also tried parsing each row as below and then run above code  scala> val rdd2 = rdd1.map(_.split('|'))
rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at <console>:29

                         ^